# Select rows in one table based on an id that appears in a column on a different table AND have multiple matches based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a very difficult question for me to formulate so the title may need review. But here's my situation:

I need to select all rows from the node table that contain a row in the field_data_field_incident_type where the entity_id matches nid 
and multiple field_incident_type_tid's which have the same entity_id as the nid.
This is some example data from the tables
[image]

For example a query I might want to do is
Select all nodes from node that have both field_incident_type_tid of 66 and 64 
which should return the rows with the nid 98603 and 98612 from the node table.
Right now I'm doing it with left joins like this

```
SELECT nid
FROM node
left JOIN field_data_field_incident_type field_data_field_incident_type
    ON node.nid = field_data_field_incident_type.entity_id
left JOIN field_data_field_incident_type field_data_field_incident_type_2
    ON field_data_field_incident_type_2.entity_id = node.nid
 WHERE field_data_field_incident_type.field_incident_type_tid = 66
   AND field_data_field_incident_type_2.field_incident_type_tid = 64
;
```

this does work but that join is creating every permutation of incident_type_tid's and gets crazy if I keep on adding more incident_type_tid requirements
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Tip 1: NEVER use `SELECT *`. Tip 2: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Also, your LEFT JOINs are actually INNER JOINs.

Comment: @Strawberry for Tip 1, In my actual environment I'm not using SELECT * but I went ahead and changed it in the question for clarity, the actual columns I'm selecting is a very long list but I only showed a small piece of the tables, so I just put something random in the SELECT as an example so it wouldn't be gigantic. For tip 2: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean I should create the query in db fiddle and insert that into my question? Or do you mean I shouldn't ask this question at all?

Comment: Re. Tip 2: For next time, it's the former, but this was a very easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach looks like this:

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , w.ant
  FROM node c
  JOIN field_data_field_incident_type y
    ON y.entity_id = c.nid 
 WHERE y.field_incident_type_tid IN(66,64)
 GROUP 
    BY c.nid 
HAVING COUNT([DISTINCT] y.field_incident_type_tid) = 2 -- WHERE '2' is equal to the number of arguments in IN().
```

Please keep any comments about syntax errors to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct node.*,field_data_field_incident_type.field_incident_type_tid
FROM node 
JOIN field_data_field_incident_type field_data_field_incident_type
ON node.nid = field_data_field_incident_type.entity_id